# MobaXterm ssh keeps getting disconnected although "SSH keepalive" is set

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, mobaxterm

Environment:

**Ubuntu 18.04 / MobaXterm personal edition v20.2 build 4296**

While connecting with ssh, even though I submitted jobs with ***nohup*** and let it work in background, it always gives me "**Network error: Software caused connection abort**".

Is there any other setup that helps prevent this kind of situation?
My network is unstable. Even though I did not put my laptop to sleep. Usually it just disconnected so my jobs are terminated.